# Receive broadcast from notification

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications

I try to send broadcast to fragment when notification arrived. I think I've done everything ok, but it doesn't work. Could you tell me what am I doing wrong ? This is how I send broadcast:

```
if (code == 1) {

                int id = Integer.parseInt(data[1]);
                int idMessage = Integer.parseInt(data[2]);
                String user = data[3];
                String messageChat = data[4];
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(arg0, ChatMainActivity.class);
                intent2.putExtra("alert", true);
                intent2.putExtra("userId", id);
                intent2.putExtra("messageId", idMessage);
                intent2.putExtra("userName", user);
                intent2.putExtra("message", messageChat);
                intent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
                intent2.setAction("mac.baseline.baselinemobile.BroadcastReceiver");
                sendBroadcast(intent2);

                PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(arg0, 0,
                        intent2, 0);

                boolean isRunning = isApplicationRunning();

                if (isRunning) {
                    intent2 = new Intent(arg0, AlertReceiver.class);
                    pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(arg0, 0, intent2, 0);
                }
                Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(arg0)
                        .setContentTitle("Baseline™")
                        .setContentText("Nowa wiadomość od: " + user + ": " + messageChat)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.alert2)
                        .setTicker(newItems)
                        .setContentIntent(pIntent).build();
```

and this is how I receive it in my fragment :

```
private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onReceive: works!");
        }

};
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("mac.baseline.baselinemobile.BroadcastReceiver");
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).
            registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
}

public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}
```

Comment: Unregister your broadcast receiver from onDestroy() instead of onPause()

Comment: Nope, it's not this thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how you are using the app. But you need to do..

> LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);

And do the register and unregister operation in onCreate() and onDestroy() method.

Answer (score 1):

Write this line

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext).sendBroadcast(intent2);
```

instead of

```
sendBroadcast(intent2);
```